# No such file or directory, opening "~/filename" from perl

Tags: perl

I am getting the "no such file or directory" error, but of course, there actually is the file in question. I am using double quotes. I am running the code in the directory where the file is located.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl;
use warnings;
use strict;
use diagnostics;

open(FASTA, "<", "~/LDTest.rtf")
```

This fails even if:

```
touch ~/LDTest.rtf
cd ~
```

...is run from the shell before starting the script, to ensure that the file exists and is in the current directory.

Comment: Echo the line to `STDERR` so that you can see exactly what it is, and consider whether there are letter-case differences if you are using a case-sensitive file system.  (In such a system, `Foo` and `foo` are not the same file.)

Comment: Shells like bash expand `~` to your home directory, so `~/LDTest.rtf` would become `/home/foo/LDTest.rtf`; Perl's `open` doesn't do this. Try passing the full path to the file.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your responses. I have checked the case- there is no difference. I changed the location to "/Users/roblogan/LDTest.rtf" and that didn't help either.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- a good StackOverflow question should include a **minimal** code sample; that is, one with only the absolute smallest amount of code that would produce the same problem; it should also be **verifiable**, so other people (not just you) can run it and get the same problem.

Comment: ...I've tried to edit this to comply with that guideline. Please consider doing likewise in creating future questions.

Comment: (also, if you'd tried simplifying before you asked -- ie. taking content *out* of a subroutine and seeing if you still had the same problem -- you would have had a better, narrower question).

Comment: Thanks for your help Charles! Will keep those points in mind for the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have problem in this line:

```
my $RawSequence = loadSequence("~/LDTest.rtf");
```

Instead of using tilde give the full path of the file:

```
my $RawSequence = loadSequence("path/to/LDTest.rtf");
```

or if you are in the same directory (meaning if you are running your program from the same directory where the file exists), just give the file name:

```
my $RawSequence = loadSequence("LDTest.rtf");
```

Comment: my $RawSequence = loadSequence("LDTest.rtf"); while in the directory itself solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Rob: If it helped you, you can accept this as an answer so this question can be closed as solved.

Comment: I just had to wait three minutes from posting to accept it. Now it should be checked as the right answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of

```
~/LDTest.rtf
```

in the shell is

```
"$ENV{HOME}/LDTest.rtf"
```

in Perl.